# c# extracting a certain value within a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to remove a certain bit of text within a string.

Say the string I have contains html elements, like paragraph tags, I created some sort of tokens that will be identified with "{" at the beginning and "}" at the end.

So essentially the string I have would look like this:

```
text = "<p>{token}</p><p> text goes here  {token3}</p>"
```

I'm wondering is there a way to extract all the words including the "{}" using C#-Code within the string.

Whilst each token could be different to the next, that is why i must use "{" and "}" to identify them as seen below

At the moment I'm got to this code:

```
var newWord = text.Contains("{") && word.Contains("}")
```

Comment: IndexOf and Substring, or a Regex.

Comment: use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
var r = new Regex("({.*?})");
foreach(var match in r.Matches(myString)) ...
```

The `?` means that your regex is non-greedy. If you omit it you´ll simply get everythinbg between the first `{` and the last `}`.

Alternativly you may also use this:

```
var index = text.IndexOf("{");
while (index != -1)
{
    var end = text.IndexOf("}", index);
    result.Add(text.Substring(index, end - index + 1));
    index = text.IndexOf("{", index + 1);
}
```

Comment: This will extract "{token}</p><p> text goes here  {token3}", default is greedy matching

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a regex for this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("{.*?}");

var results = reg.Matches(text);
```

The regex searches for any characters between `{` and `}`.
The `.*?` means match any character but in a non greedy way. So it will search for the shortest possible string between braces.